# Wordpress redirection issue , any http url redirects to https homepage

Tags: wordpress, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I m using IIS and I have a wordpress installation and SSL installed. Any url requests which include http (eg: http://example.com/fooBar), redirects to https://example.com homepage.I expect **http**://example.com/fooBar redirects to **https**://example.com/fooBar.  What am i missing? 
Also, I am open for hardcoded solutions. Honestly i have 2 specific http urls to redirect to their https versions.

Answer (score 1):

You may add this on your functions.php

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_core', 50);
add_action('init', 'redirect_core', 50);
add_action('wp_loaded', 'redirect_core', 50);
function redirect_core(){
  if (!is_ssl()) {
    wp_redirect('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301);
    exit();
  }
}
```

or use this plugin: [HTTPS Redirection](https://github.com/vindecodex/wp-https-redirect/blob/master/https-redirect.php)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you will need to edit the sites 'Base URL' to include 'https'. This can be done by going to your admin panel>General Settings and updating the 'WordPress Address (URL)' and the 'Site Address (URL)'. Make sure that your .htaccess has the correct permissions set for this to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. They are already https. I am using IIS so i have webconfig file. And nothing seems to wrong in it.

Comment: My apologies, didn't see that you're using IIS, you could try using a URL rewrite module, please see url: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2016/06/07/redirect-from-http-to-https-using-the-iis-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: you can use $url = home_url( '/', 'https' );
echo esc_url( $url );

Comment: where should i use this use $url = home_url( '/', 'https' ); echo esc_url( $url );  exactly?